# Is video not allowed in a Spotify App?

Tags: html5-video, spotify

I have tried this (using the  html 5 tag), but get unexpected results. I didn't find any clear documentation that it is *not* supported, but I can't get it to work so far.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 video tag is not supported by the Spotify client.

For a detailed overview of what's supported, choose "Show HTML5 Support" from the "Develop" menu in Spotify.

Comment: Great, thanks for that. For some reason (update this morning?), that option shows up in my Help menu now.

Comment: Also, just to confirm, this would effectively mean that video is not allowed by Spotify? (I.E. there is no work-around for supression of the video tag?)

Comment: The Show HTML5 Support menu item has been there for months. And you're correct, there's no supported way to get video into a Spotify app.